# How can I find the source of a <script> placed in the footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could shed some insight onto a problem I'm having.

The code below is from the footer of a WordPress website I run, and as you'll notice, the second script is invalid. I have no idea where that even came from or how to fix it, and I've searched through many WordPress PHP files (footer.php, index.php, page.php, etc.) to try to find the source, but I'm not sure where it is.

So my question is this: could someone tell me how to find the source of this script? In other words, how can I find out where that second line of code even comes from? I'm not a developer, so sorry if this is a dumb question. Here's the code for you to reference:

```
<script defer="defer" src="http://echidnainc.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://echidnainc.comhttp//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://echidnainc.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-social-share-buttons/assets/js/easy-social-share-buttons.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://echidnainc.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-social-share-buttons/assets/js/essb-sticky-sidebar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script defer="defer" src="http://echidnainc.com/wp-content/plugins/easy-slide-in/optin-forms-manager/js/placeholder.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: There's plenty of reasons this could be going wrong and be placed there.  It could be because of a widget you downloaded to wordpress, it could be in your theme's footer, etc.  It's hard to tell without more info which would be hard to get from you with you not being a developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed to each of the scripts you mentioned in your post (just pasted the link into my browser to see the JavaScript source). It doesn't seem to be any of those scripts that are adding the tag to Google's hosted version of jQuery.

My suggestion, without knowing the source of the plugins you have in your wordpress, is that one of the plugins is trying to include jQuery, and has an error.

As to why the scripts are loaded at the end of the page, this is a combination of the "defer" tag, combined with a common web development trick that placing  tags at the end of the page body facilitates faster load times.

If you could refer to the source code for any of the plugins I don't mind checking to see which one, if any, have the typo. You yourself could attempt to remove plugins one by one to see if one causes the script tag to disappear, and boom, culprit.

Comment: Thanks Tyler -- my original question was a bit confusing, as I wasn't actually trying to ask why the scripts were in the footer, but thanks for the input on that.

I might try to disable the plugins one at a time as you recommended to find out which one is the culprit.

Comment: Keep this updated, I'll check back and do my best. I've done a lot of development with Wordpress both to the Wordpress repository itself as well as many, many websites, and I have run into this problem often. Could be a typo somewhere, could be something more serious. @ntgCleaner's comment is also very true in this situation.

Comment: I figured out the culprit plugin. I'll put in in a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

So to answer the general question I posed, to find the source of a  line of code placed in the footer of a WordPress page, the first thing to try should probably be the one-by-one deactivation of plugins until the script disappears (and obviously, when the script disappears, then you know the last plugin to be deactivated was responsible). That worked for me.

And now for details on my specific situation's resolution:
A plugin, Speed Booster Pack, was causing the erroneous script:

`<script defer=”defer” src=”http://echidnainc.comhttp//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>`

Either that erroneous script or another element of the Speed Booster Pack was interfering with another plugin I recently installed. I tried tweaking some PHP files in the Speed Booster Pack, but ultimately I just deactivated the plugin in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Would appreciate some attribution :)

Comment: How do I give attribution? Sorry, I'm new here.

Comment: Just an upvote, or accept my answer if it helped you. Just helps people in the future if they find your question that the advice I offered was helpful.

Comment: Okay cool, I accepted the answer. Would've upvoted it but my rep isn't high enough yet.

Answer (score 0):

The second script is invalid, because the url in the `src="..."` arrtibute is invalid. I assume you wanted to use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a JavaScript libary.
To fix that replace
`src="http://echidnainc.comhttp//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"`
with 
`src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.js"`
The jQuery libary hosted by Google.

Comment: Yeah, I know that's the reason why the script is invalid; my question was more along the lines of how to figure out why the src is being populated as such. Sorry if the question wasn't clear enough.